# How to keep moving PictureBox in boundaries C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, screensaver, bounce

I am writing a bouncing logo screensaver in Visual Studio 2010 using C#.  I have never written in C# before today so I am apologizing for any ignorance in advanced.  I am importing an image to the form using PictureBox. Is there a way to find the boundaries of the PictureBox so I can compare it to the boundaries of the screen (using screen.Bounds for screen boundaries)?  Like I said, I've never programmed in C# before so I am not sure what other details you will need, if any.  Please let me know and I'll put up whatever I can.  Thank you.

EDIT:
My bounce method is written in public partial class ScreensaverForm.  The frame is in static class Program.  My boundary check in the bounce method is if(picturebox.Bounds.Bottom == this.Bounds.Bottom).  This seems to check for boundaries, but the boundaries are not the boundaries of the frame.  How do I call the frame attributes?

Comment: I understand you haven't programmed in c#, but you need to at least show us what you've tried/googled

Comment: It appears that I have gotten ahead of myself.  I have tried testing PictureBox.Bounds.Top == this.Bounds.Top, but I just realized my move method does not work.  I thought I was creating a Point(x,y), but I seem to have done that incorrectly. Just fixed the point.  Will go back and test.

Comment: After some testing, it looks like picturebox.bounds.top == this.bounds.top is close.  Instead of this, I need to use the bounds of the frame.  The code for the bounce method and the creation of the frame are done in to separate places.  The bounce method is created in public partial class ScreensaverForm, while the frame is created in static class Program.  How do I access the frame attributes from the bounce method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something.

Get the Screenbounds as a `Rectangle`.

```
screenrectangle.Contains(new Rectangle(MyPictureBox.Location, MyPictureBox.Size))
```

will give you true if it's all on screen.

Comment: I need to know what boundary it is hitting so I can reverse direction.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this, but this looks like it only tells me whether or not I am in bounds.  This does not tell me if I am hitting a particular boundary.

Comment: Well if you were in bounds and you would't be if you moved... Depends on whether you know which direction you are moving, but  MyPictureBox.Location.X + MyPictureBox.Size.Width > Screen.Bounds.Right or some such ...

Answer (score 0):

Your picturebox will live in a form.  The picturebox has a Bounds which provides you the top, left, right, and bottom values relative to the form in which it is contained.  From there, you can easily calculate if the picturebox is completely within the form or not using the Forms width and height property, assuming that the top left corner is 0,0.  As you move the picturebox, you check to ensure that the move you are about to do will keep the picturebox within the form.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tony's excellent suggestion, I would like to adress how to handle collision:

There are four boundaries, so there are four situations to check.

It is possible to have a horizontal and vertical bounce at the same time! Therefore keep track of horizontal and vertical speed independently, a horizontal bounce will only affect horizontal motion.

In addition, if your object moves more than one pixel at a time, you may not see an exact hit. (Like that the x coordinate of your box moves directly from 1 to -1 without being 0. So you should test if the boundary is **on or over** the boundary, not just test for on.

It is also good practice to only check for collision when you move towards a particular boundary. If you don't your window might get stuck because it collides with the same edge after every move.