# How do I stop the animated movement of an object at the edge of the window?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I wanted to make on winforms an animation with an object but when it goes to the edge, it doesn't stop. It goes outside of the form
what should I do?

Comment: You could start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537906/how-to-keep-moving-picturebox-in-boundaries-c-sharp-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. Please add details to your question to help us help you. You can take a look at [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) for hints in improving your question.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project add a pictureBox in it with a picture or just simply a background color and apply these codes. This will give you an idea how to do it.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 12;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    int difference = 5;
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Left  < 0 || pictureBox1.Left + pictureBox1.Width > this.Width) difference = -difference;
        pictureBox1.Left += difference;
    }
```